# How to write a regex for a sui address of length 64 eg. “0x02…5f331”?

Tags: sui

How to write a regex to be used in TypeScript for a Sui address as seen on the Sui explorer.
eg. the address "0xf821d3483fc7725ebafaa5a3d12373d49901bdfce1484f219daa7066a30df77d"
as seen on
https://suiexplorer.com/address/0xf821d3483fc7725ebafaa5a3d12373d49901bdfce1484f219daa7066a30df77d

It should not give a match if a user copied an adresss and some symbols where missing or when it is not a valid Sui address. eg.
2 missing symbols: "0xf821d3483fc7725ebafaa5a3d12373d491bdfce1484f219daa7066a30df77d"

I would like to use the regex in my TypeScript function.
I did some trials on regex101.com but have troubles coming up with the correct regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
0[xX][a-fA-F0-9]{64}
```

[Explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1LKccD/1)

Why not {1,64} to allow for 0x2, 0xdeed, etc.?

When users copy an address from their wallet or the [sui explorer](https://suiexplorer.com/), it is always full-length, leading zeros are not trimmed. A shorter address likely means that the user deleted some characters by mistake. So, I want to check that all 64 characters are there for my use case. But for other use cases, {1,64} could make more sense (e.g. libraries).

You can also use the function `isValidSuiAddress` from the [typescript SDK](http://typescript-sdk-docs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/functions/isValidSuiAddress.html) to test if a Sui address is correct.

Credit to Juzy for the original answer on Telegram.

Comment: Depending on whether it should find an address in a string or actually validate a string that's supposed to contain (only) an address, you'd have to wrap it in `^ $`. Also, it would be easier to make the regex case-insensitive than specifying both upper and lower case. You would then end up with `/^0x[0-9a-f]{64}$/i`.